# I cannot create react app with the help of create-react-app crudapp

Tags: reactjs

I tried to create react app using `create-react-app crudapp`, then I cannot create it. Instead, I got an error which I have attached below.

I tried to search everywhere but I could get my answer.

[image]

Comment: did you try **npx create-react-app crudapp**?

Comment: same problem. But problem solved now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your npm is corrupt, might be worth a try to reinstall it.

Comment: thanks. Problem solved.